# Why my theme option not working?

Tags: theme-development, theme-options, troubleshooting

I am looking for the bugs about an hour but i can't find anything. Can you look and say why my theme option is not working?

**Problem:**
The theme option not saving. Even the default option is also blank. I checked the value via php my admin.

Check the code in pastebin. And also how i can debug this kinds of problem?

http://pastebin.com/TPV5YvD9

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little tricky to say by looking at code alone.

The first thing you need to check in such cases - if your validation function receives data from submitted form. `var_dump()` input and `die;` right after that to stop execution and prevent redirect back.

Depending on what you get there (if anything) check back through Settings API functions. There are a lot of arguments to juggle with those and it is easy to mix then up.

Answer (score 0):

very hard to say exactly where it is dying.  i used to try to handle my own theme options, but now there are so many good plugins that handle all the hard parts for me i can just focus on actually creating the options i need for my clients.

i'm partial to Devin Price's Options Framework:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/options-framework/

but i've heard good things about OptionTree and Fitr
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/theme-options

just a suggestion, sorry i couldn't help more.